# Given a domain name get a list of urls that start with a pattern

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

For example, the domain is https://example.com/, and there are only those 4 subdomains

- https://example.com/p_1
- https://example.com/p_2
- https://example.com/p_3
- https://example.com/a_1

So if I specify `https://example.com/p_`, then I would get the the first 3 urls.

How do I use a crawler to do this?

Answer (score 2):

In scrapy there is `Linkextractor` [here](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/link-extractors.html)

They are used to specify the `url` style to crawl by passing `regex`.To use this you also need to inherit from `CrawlSpider` instead of `Spider` and import some libraries.

you can use, like,

```
Rule(
    LinkExtractor(`regex(.*/p_.?)`, callback=function_name)
)
```

More you can read in docs.

Comment: Yeah, scrapy's ```LinkExtractor``` was made for this such use case.

Answer (score 0):

FYI, in the example you provided, those aren't subdomains, but are URI paths.

In Python 3:

```py
import urllib.parse

def gen_uri_paths(baseURL, append_paths):
    res = urllib.parse.urlparse(baseURL)
    uri_paths = []
    for p in append_paths:
        u = list(res)
        u[2] += p
        uri_paths.append(urllib.parse.ParseResult(*u).geturl())
    return uri_paths

# Returns ['https://example.com/p_1', 'https://example.com/p_2', 'https://example.com/p_3', 'https://example.com/a_1']
gen_uri_paths("https://example.com", ["p_1", "p_2", "p_3", "a_1"])
```

For crawling, look into [scrapy](https://scrapy.org/)